# The html td is not updating via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this little method which, on the first load, created a `<tr>` and some `<td>'s`. That works.  But if the underlying data changes, the `<td>'s` are not updated. I'm not sure why.

```
    function ParseJson(json, isFirstLoad)
    {
        json = $.parseJSON(json);
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            if (isFirstLoad === 1)
            {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td id='" + json[i].LocationName + "'>" + json[i].LocationName + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td id='" + json[i].LocationName + "Count'>" + json[i].Count + "</td>");
                $('#MainTable').append(tr);
            }
            else
            {
                var td =  $("#" + json[i].LocationName + "Count");
                td.html = json[i].Count;
            }
        }
```

When isFirstLoad is 1, the html is rendered as I would expect. Example:

```
<tr>
    <td id="ChemLab">ChemLab</td>
    <td id="ChemLabCount">24</td>
</tr>
```

But the next time around, if the data has changed and someone has left the Chem Lab, the html for ChemLabCount does not change.

I have verified that the json being passed into this method is correct.  Meaning, the count DOES indeed change.  It just doesn't get displayed on the screen.

Comment: I think it should be `td.html(json[i].Count);` or `td.text(json[i].Count);`   ?

Comment: You are using "id" in for loop so you'll have multiple tags with the same id... try to use class property.

Comment: Sorry you got a fiery response on your now-deleted thread! We have some members who get a bit burnt-out and, although a lot of their material is helpful, they are prone to getting impatient, and sometimes cross the line from abrupt to rude. Feel free to raise mod flags in the future, especially if that means you can then persist with your question.

Comment: @halfer, appreciate it.  That guy WAS rude. But he also had a point.  I really hadn't done my due diligence before asking the question.  That being said, still no excuse for being rude. Thanks for the moral support :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a function, not a property.

```
td.html(json[i].Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from `td.html = json[i].Count;` because it's not the right way of using `html()` method.

To set the `Count` to your `td` you could use `.text()` instead :

```
td.text( json[i].Count );
```

Else if you want to set an HTML code the you could use `.html()` :

```
td.html( json[i].Count );
```